# Check if value is string or only integer?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a list which is being populated from the database. The list is of this format:

```
class Event
{
    public int EventID { get; set; }
    public string EventName { get; set; }
    public string EventManager { get; set; }
    public int EventManagerID { get; set; }
    public string EventTicketID { get; set; }
}

class Manager
{
    public int ManagerID { get; set; }
    public string ManagerName { get; set; }
    public string ManagerShortName { get; set; }
    public bool IsActive { get; set; }
}
```

The EventTicketID is usually populated by an integer. But at times, the ticketID also has strings in it. This happens when an Event Manager sub-contracts to another management company in which case the EventTicketId is populated with the format ManagerShortName_TicketID. I want to know check if an event is contracted to an event manager or is contracted to a sub-manager. So I want to check if the EventTickedId is an integer or has strings in it.

I tried checking by using:

```
//EventList being populated from db in an instance of List<Event> called listEvents
int directContractTicketID = Convert.ToInt32(listEvent[0].EventTicketID);
```

But I get Unhandled exception. can someone tell me how I can check if if EventTicketId is string or integer?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use [`int.TryParse`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.int32.tryparse.aspx) it will return `true` if the value is parsable to `int` , otherwise `false`. If the return value is `false`, then you can safely assume that the string contains some non-numeric value.

```
int directContractTicketID;
if (int.TryParse(listEvent[0].EventTicketID, out directContractTicketID))
{
    // valid int value, parsed value in directContractTicketID
}
else
{
    //  listEvent[0].EventTicketID contains some non-numeric value
}
```

Comment: I upvoted all answers as they all helped me. Your's and Bradley's answer offers exactly the same solution. I marked it as his was first as well as edited the question.

Comment: @JonathanDonell, you are free to accept any answer you think, but mine was first :P :)

Answer (score 4):

`Convert.ToInt32` actually calls `int.Parse` which will throw if the string is invalid (hence your unhandled exception).

Better would be to use `int.TryParse`:

```
int parsedTicket;
if (int.TryParse(listEvent[0].EventTicketID, out parsedTicket))
{
   //Value is held in parsedTicket
}
else
{
   //Ticket was not a number, parsedTicket is 0.
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to understand the use of these functions.

`Convert.toInt32` is used for conversion to integer type. Its not supposed to be used for checking if a value is integer or not.

`Int.TryParse` is a function specifically designed for that and that purpose only. To check if a given value is integer or not.

Similarly, there is a `TryParse` method for all built-in types in C#.

Hope this helps!!!

Answer (score 1):

You can use the fact that numbers do not allow underscores to find out if this is a plain number of a `ManagerShortName_TicketID`:

```
bool isSubcontracted = ticketId.Contains("_");
```

If you want to parse the ticket identifier both for plain numbers and subcontracted items, you can do it like this:

```
int ticketNumber;
string subcontractor = null;
string[] tokens = ticketId.Split('_');
if (tokens.Length == 2) {
    subcontractor = tokens[0];
    ticketNumber = int.ParseInt(tokens[1]);
} else {
    ticketNumber = int.ParseInt(tokens[0]);
}
```